# How can I make a webpage disable using css

Tags: css

Can any one tell me how to make a web page disable using CSS.It means user will not be able to click on the any content of the web page one screen type of things will be there and user will  only able to see the content bellow the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure but if you mean user should only see content and be not able to click anywhere, you can create an overlay with CSS:

```
#overlay {
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 background:#fff;
 opacity: 0.1;
 filter: alpha(opacity=10);
}
```

This CSS will apply the overlay on entire screen, however if you want to do this to a certain part of the page then you need to adjust the values for these properties:

```
 top:0;
 left:0;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
```

Comment: yes,I want exactly this.But in my aspx where I will add this class to create the overlay on the entire screen?

Comment: @Skymoon: Yes you need to apply the css to create an overlay for entire screen or adjust the values to apply a particular portion of your document as i have said in my answer.

Comment: But content bellow the overlay is still selectable.I want the content should not be selected when overlay is applied.